# Iterate through different elements of arcGis map with svg using javascript/dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, svg, arcgis

I am using a specific map with different layers and elements on it. The map is created using `arcGis` and it creates an `<svg></svg>` label with all the elements inside (building, roads, etc.).

My question is, could I iterate through the different objects of the map inside the frame with javascript/dojo?

The main idea is to change the color of a building or a square inside the map client-side. Any idea?

HTML:

Javascript:

```
basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://...", {});
map.addLayer(basemap);
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to create an empty query that can iterate through all the elements, something like this:

```
      //initialize query task
      queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("https://...");

      //initialize query
      query = new esri.tasks.Query();
      query.returnGeometry = true;
      query.outFields = ["SPAT_NAME"];
      query.where = "1=1";

      //execute query
      queryTask.execute(query,function(results){
        console.log(results);
        console.log(elements);
        for (var i=0, il=results.features.length; i<il; i++) {
          var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
          //do stuff
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SVG is already available in the DOM, the answer to your question would be...

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("svg *");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
     if(condition) elements[i].setAttribute("fill", "red");
  }
```

However, this is a very wasteful as you are iterating through everything. If the element "names" are `id`s then you could do...

```
  ["B45","K56","L67"].forEach(function(name){
    var element = document.getElementById(name);
    if (element) element.setAttribute("fill", "red");
  });
```

Comment: I cannot iterate like this through the svg element because it has no elements define inside, this is the svg element I get after initializating the webpage:
<svg width="550" height="500" style="overflow: visible; position: absolute;" id="map_gc"><g id="graphicsLayer2_layer" style="display: none;"></g><defs></defs><g id="map_graphics_layer" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" style="display: block;"></g></svg>